# How can I overlap the Navigation in Bootstrap with more elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make a fixed navbar and two sticky-top navbars that are ON the fixed navbar.

Actually I've a fixed navbar and one navbar who is ON the fixed navbar. The first sticky navbar is one the left side and it works, but when I try to float the second sticky navbar to the right it stays on the left side on the first sticky navbar.
Here is the example I did with wix.com: [Example](https://www.fabicki.de/)

```html
<!--Navigation-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand d-lg-none" href="#">Fabicki.de</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="">Start <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle px-lg-4" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Unser Angebot
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="tueren">Türen</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="fenster">Fenster</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="sonstiges">Sonstiges</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="#ueberuns">Über uns</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="#projekte">Projekte</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!--Navigation-->

<!--Logonav-->
<nav class="navbar sticky-top position-fixed navbar-dark bg-purple round-rb shadow">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-5 d-inline-flex" href="">
        <img src="{% static 'web/images/Logo_transparent_klein.png' %}" height="73" alt="Startseite">
        <div class="col my-auto">
      <span class="h4 ml-5 m">
         <b>F.T.F.</b>
      </span><br>
      <span class="ml-5">
         FABICKI
      </span>
        </div>
    </a>
</nav>
<!--Logonav-->

<!--second nav (a btn)-->
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-purple round-b mr-5 shadow">
  <a class="navbar-brand mx-3" href="#kontakt"><b>Kontakt</b></a>
</nav>
<!--second nav (a btn)-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. I put the logo and contact btn in a container and use float-right. Now i have two navs.

```
<!--Navigation-->
same as my first post
<!--Navigation-->
```

---

```
<!--Second nav-->
<div class="container-fluid sticky-top ml-n3 position-fixed">
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top position-fixed navbar-dark bg-purple round-rb shadow">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-5 d-inline-flex" href="">
            <img src="{% static 'web/images/Logo_transparent_klein.png' %}" height="73" alt="Startseite">
            <div class="col my-auto">
              <span class="h4 ml-5 m">
                 <b>F.T.F.</b>
              </span><br>
              <span class="ml-5">
                 FABICKI
              </span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </nav>

    <nav class="navbar sticky-top float-right navbar-dark bg-purple round-b mr-5 shadow">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-3" href="#kontakt"><b>Kontakt</b></a>
    </nav>
</div>
<!--Second nav-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make three navbar like that ! Try this it should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!--This is your first NavBar with Image on Left Side-->
    <img class="img-responsive nav navbar-nav navbar-left" src="umbrella.png"> <!-- Put Your Logo Image Here-->
    </img>
    <!--This is your second Navbar with links and other stuffs-->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--This is your third Navbar with your custom text-->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <a href="#"><b>Kontakt</b></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( now everything is scrolling. But only the logo and the contact button have to. But thanks for the answer :)